# Getting text and links from a web page

Tags: w3m

I would like to have a script that downloads a web page with curl, pipes it to w3m, which is stripping it from all content except text and links.

Is it possible to specify for the -T option of w3m, more than just one content-type and how?

To clarify my question a bit more, here's an example:

`curl --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0" https://askubuntu.com/questions -s | w3m -dump -T text/html`

which returns only text from Ask Ubuntu's questions page but with no links. If w3m cannot do it is there any other tool which is capable of scraping text and links simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Well, after extensive research on my own, I guess, there is no such a tool...

However, for what it's worth, I did discover hxnormalize which made writting a particular script I needed, a relatively simple matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lynx -dump`. It will include a number like `[16]` before each link, and then a list of URLs at the end of the document.

For pipe usage, you can use `lynx -dump -force_html -stdin`. However, that will not handle relative links correctly because it doesn't know the original URL.

So the best way is to do `lynx -dump http://.../` without separate `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `-o display_link_number=1` does what you want, as in:

```
$ w3m -dump -o display_link_number=1 http://example.org
Example Domain

This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.

[1]More information...


References:

[1] https://www.iana.org/domains/example
```